# Question about Bell state analyzers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Is there a Bell state analyzer that would take as input 2 qubits in Bell state, distinguish between psi and phi states and  send psi states to output A and phi states to output B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Since all Bell states are orthogonal, you can just measure in the Bell basis. Depending on the outcome, you prepare the same Bell state again (if your measurement was destructive; otherwise you still have that Bell state) and send it to the desired output.

Comment: So it can't be done without destructive measurement?

Comment: What about Hong–Ou–Mandel effect? Does that also destroy half of the qubits?

Comment: Sure it can be done with a non-desctructive measurement. You even save the work to re-prepare the state since you did not destroy it. Just that in practice, measurements are often desctructive.

Comment: If you detect the photons in Hong-Ou-Mandel, then it is desctructive, since the photon detector destroys the photons.  Unless you don't measure the photons because they took the other port, then they are still there.

Comment: So theoretically the Bell state analyzer could work deterministically without destroying the Bell states?

Comment: If the qubits A and B in Bell state are entangled to qubits C and D respectively then the entanglement between AC and BD would also be preserved after the Bell state analysis?

Comment: (i) Yes, it could work without destroying the qubits. (Why not?)

Comment: (ii) If A and B are in a Bell state, they **cannot** be entangled to anything else: This is the monogamy of entanglement: http://www.quantiki.org/wiki/Monogamy_of_entanglement

Comment: I was referring to entanglement swapping where AB from two entangled pairs AC and BD  are projected into Bell state by joint Bell measurement. So CD would be orthogonal to AB. So if AB are sent through the Bell analyzer would CD still be orthogonal to AB?

Comment: Note that StackExchange is a Question&Answer site, not a discussion board about physics.